# Compute $\mathbb{Z}/m\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n$ using exact sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I want to compute $\mathbb{Z}/m\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n$ using exact sequence as follows.

Consider the exact sequence
$$
\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/m\to 0.
$$
Tensoring with $\mathbb{Z}/n$ gives
$$
\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n\to\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n\to\mathbb{Z}/m\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n\to 0.
$$
The first map is given by $(\times m)\otimes1$. By exactness, $\mathbb{Z}/m\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n$ mod the image of the first map which is $m\mathbb{Z}\otimes\mathbb{Z}/n$? But I don't know how to proceed further...

Comment: What is the cokernel of multiplication by $m$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/n$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/n$, and that the first arrow $\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/n \to \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/n$ identifies with the multiplication by $m$ map $\mathbb{Z}/n \to \mathbb{Z}/n$ in the sense that the composition $$\mathbb{Z}/n \cong \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/n \to \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/n \cong \mathbb{Z}/n$$ is multiplication by $m$. Does this help?

Comment: I edited the question to clarify what I meant. The image of that arrow is $m\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/n = \mathbb{Z} \otimes mZ/n$.

Comment: Since $\text{gcd}(m,n)$ divides $n$, there is a (unique) homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/n \to \mathbb{Z}/\text{gcd}(m,n)$, namely $1 \mapsto 1$. You should check that the kernel of this map is $m\mathbb{Z}/n$.